# Postgress Group BY with to_tsquery

Tags: postgresql

I use psql (11.7). I have table ptoducts where I created GIN index for search by text fields

```
create index ndsprc_swedish_custom_index on products
using GIN(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',coalesce(name,'')||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')||' '||coalesce(shop,'')))
```

and there is my query for search products with limit and offset

```
SELECT                         
products_alias.id,
products_alias.sku,
products_alias.name AS "name",
products_alias.description,
products_alias.category,
products_alias.price,
products_alias.shipping,
products_alias.currency,
products_alias.instock,
products_alias.product_url AS "productUrl",
products_alias.image_url AS "imageUrl",
products_alias.tracking_url AS "trackingUrl",
products_alias.brand,
products_alias.shop,
products_alias.original_price AS "originalPrice",
products_alias.ean,
products_alias.manufacturer_article_number AS "manufacturerArticleNumber",
products_alias.extras,
products_alias.created_at AS "createdAt",
products_alias.brand_relation_id AS "brandRelationId",
products_alias.shop_relation_id AS "shopRelationId",
array_agg(DISTINCT cpt.category_id) AS categoryIds,
COUNT(DISTINCT uip.id) as "numberOfEntries",   
ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',coalesce(name,'')||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')||' '||coalesce(shop,'')), query_search) AS rank

FROM products products_alias 

JOIN to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'dress:*') query_search
ON to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',coalesce(name,'')||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')||' '||coalesce(shop,'')) @@ query_search

LEFT JOIN product_category cp on cp.product_id = products_alias.id
LEFT JOIN product_category cpt on cpt.product_id = products_alias.id
LEFT JOIN user_ip_product uip on uip.products_id = products_alias.id               

GROUP BY products_alias.id, query_search.query_search ORDER BY rank DESC, "numberOfEntries" DESC

LIMIT 10
OFFSET 0
```

and some products have the same `product_url` but different `extras` (JSONB type). Hot to group by `GROUP BY product_url`(VARCHAR type) and merge `extras` result in one field and saveing `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` ?

without search it's looks ilke this

```
SELECT                         
products_alias.product_url,
array_agg(products_alias.id) AS ids,
array_agg(products_alias.extras) AS extras_merge

FROM products products_alias 
GROUP BY products_alias.product_url
```

and I have correct result, because I have two id with the same `product_url`

```
product_url | ids         | extras_merge
7942010-80   | {3004,3002} | {{extras1},{extras2}}
7942010-81   | {3003}      | {{extras1}}
```

When I use subquery it's works, but how to refactor it to one query ?

```
SELECT                         

array_agg(DISTINCT main_products_alias.id) AS ids,
array_agg(DISTINCT main_products_alias.name) AS names,
array_agg(DISTINCT main_products_alias.extras) AS extras

FROM (
SELECT                         
products_alias.id,
products_alias.sku,
products_alias.name AS "name",
products_alias.description,
products_alias.category,
products_alias.price,
products_alias.shipping,
products_alias.currency,
products_alias.instock,
products_alias.product_url AS "productUrl",
products_alias.image_url AS "imageUrl",
products_alias.tracking_url AS "trackingUrl",
products_alias.brand,
products_alias.shop,
products_alias.original_price AS "originalPrice",
products_alias.ean,
products_alias.manufacturer_article_number AS "manufacturerArticleNumber",
products_alias.extras,
products_alias.created_at AS "createdAt",
products_alias.brand_relation_id AS "brandRelationId",
products_alias.shop_relation_id AS "shopRelationId",
array_agg(DISTINCT cpt.category_id) AS categoryIds,
COUNT(DISTINCT uip.id) as "numberOfEntries"

,ts_rank_cd(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',coalesce(name,'')||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')||' '||coalesce(shop,'')), query_search) AS rank

FROM products products_alias 

JOIN to_tsquery('pg_catalog.swedish', 'dress:*') query_search
ON to_tsvector('pg_catalog.swedish',coalesce(name,'')||' '||coalesce(description,'')||' '||coalesce(sku,'')||' '||coalesce(price,0)||' '||coalesce(category,'')||' '||coalesce(brand,'')||' '||coalesce(shop,'')) @@ query_search

LEFT JOIN product_category cp on cp.product_id = products_alias.id
LEFT JOIN product_category cpt on cpt.product_id = products_alias.id
LEFT JOIN user_ip_product uip on uip.products_id = products_alias.id               

GROUP BY products_alias.id, query_search.query_search ORDER BY rank DESC, "numberOfEntries" DESC
) AS main_products_alias

GROUP BY main_products_alias."productUrl"
```

Comment: You already have something that works.  Why not use what works?  And this has nothing to do with ts_query.

Comment: @jjanes it directly depends from `to_tsquery`, because  `to_tsquery`  search text by `query_search` which use GIN index in `to_tsvector`. If I did not use seacrh, I not needed group by column from index and grouping by  `productUrl` works correct. About why I want refactoring this, because subquery waste more resources instead one query

Comment: If the query that works is too slow, post an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of it, preferably with track_io_timing turned on, so we can help improve it.